# Clean TextField when BottomSheetScaffold collapse on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm having a little trouble adding a form inside a Bottom sheet because every time I open the bottomSheet, the previous values continue there. I'm trying to make something like this

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun BottomSheet() {
    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
    )
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            Form {
                // save foo somewhere
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                }
            }
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp
    ) {
        Button(onClick = {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = "Expand")
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun Form(
    onSaveFoo: (String) -> Unit
) {
    var foo by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Column {
        Button(onClick = {
            onSaveFoo(foo)
        }) {
            Text(text = "Save")
        }
        OutlinedTextField(value = foo, onValueChange = { foo = it })
    }
}
```

There is a way to "clean" my form every time the bottom sheet collapses without manually setting all values to `""` again?

Something like the BottomShettFragment. If I close and reopen the BottomSheetFragment, the previous values will not be there.

Comment: Could it be due to `remember`? It remembers the previous value after re-compose

Comment: But if I don't put remember, the `OutlinedTextField` do not work

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, they say that it is better to control your state outside of a composable function (in a viewmodel) and pass it as a parameter.

You may clear the textField value, when you decide to collapse your bottomSheet, for example in `onSaveFoo` function.

Add a MutableStateFlow to your viewmodel, subscribe to its updates via collectAsState extension in your composable. You can get a viewmodel by a composable function viewModel(ViewModelClass::class.java).

In onSaveFoo function update your state with new string or empty string if that's the behaviour you want to achieve. State updates should happen inside viewmodel. So create a method in your viewmodel to update your state and call it when you want to collapse your bottomsheet to clear the text contained in your state.

And another thing, `remember` saves the value across recompositions. The value will be lost only if your Composable is removed from the Composition. It will happen if you change the content of your bottomSheet.
Something like this:

```
    sheetContent = {
     if(bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isExpanded){
        Form {
            // save foo somewhere
            coroutineScope.launch {
                bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
            }
        }
      }else{
       Spacer(modifier=Modifier.height(16.dp).background(Color.White)//or some other composable
       }
    },
```